# Как отключить "Умный режим" контроля активности на телефоне XIAOMI

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Свое приложение я устанавливаю на XIAOMI 9T.
По умолчанию на телефоне установлен контроль активности "Умный режим", который я хотел бы снять для работы моего приложения.

При начале работы программы я смог открыть панель "Контроль активности", чтоб пользователь вручную отключил "Умный режим":

```
CN := TJComponentName.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.miui.powerkeeper'), StringToJString('com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity'));
 Intent := TJIntent.Create;
 Intent.setComponent(CN);
 Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('package_name') , StringToJString('com.embarcadero.' + ProgramNane));
 Intent.PutExtra(StringToJString('package_label'), StringToJString(ProgramNane));
 SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```

Но это не совсем удобно.
Хотелось, чтобы программно можно было отключить данный режим, установив контроль активности "Без ограничений", чтобы не напрягать пользователя.
Но как это сделать я не знаю.
Просьба помочь!

Можно ли вообще не показывать панель "Контроль активности", а программно всегда устанавливать опцию "Без ограничений"?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, так как у приложения недостаточно прав на изменение системных настроек. У Xiaomi очень жёсткая политика контроля активности приложений, так что открыть пользователю нужный пункт в настройках - максимум, что можно сделать

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ли определить при загрузке приложения какой режим установлен, чтоб каждый раз не показывать пользователю панель "Контроль активности" для выбора нужного режима?

Comment: Как вы заходите в настройки? Можно код?

Comment: Код указан выше - это рабочий вход в настройки:

Comment: CN := TJComponentName.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.miui.powerkeeper'), StringToJString('com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity'));
 Intent := TJIntent.Create;
 Intent.setComponent(CN);
 Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('package_name') , StringToJString('com.embarcadero.' + ProgramNane));
 Intent.PutExtra(StringToJString('package_label'), StringToJString(ProgramNane));
 SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);